# How to get background image on each repeat print page properly?

Tags: html, css

I have a html page which takes content from database and on behave of that content , I print pages.
The issue is that on each print page the background image is not properly set. The background image is acting like a watermark on each print page.

The result of background image on each print page should be like this:

[image: proper print on each page]

but the result on print I am getting is these problems.

1) The image in single print page is shown twice.

[image: repeat image background]

2) Second which is major issue is that when content finishes the image is shown in half.

[image: on content finish image shown in half]

This is the html page:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/custom/css/print.css') }}">
  <link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/custom/js/customMainFunction.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-right">
        <?php echo CommonHelper::displayPrintButtonInBlade('PrintHrWarningLetter','','1');?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container print-container" id="PrintHrWarningLetter" style="page-break-after: always;">
    <div class="bg_image last_image">
        <div class="bg_color">
            <div class="print-font page">
                <div class="row warning-top-mar letter-head">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <p>{{date('F d, Y')}}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row letter-head">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 war-margin1">
                        <p><b>Subject:</b>   <b class="bor-bot">Warning Letter</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row letter-head">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 warning-mar2">
                        <p class="warning-line-hei war-margin1 page" >
                            <?php echo nl2br($hr_warning_letter->letter_content1) ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--<?php if($hr_warning_letter->letter_content2 != '<p><br></p>') { ?>
                    <div class="row page-break2" style="margin-top:50px;">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 warning-mar2">
                            <p class="warning-line-hei war-margin1">
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }?>-->
                <div class="row page-break2" style="margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 warning-mar2">
                        <p class="warning-line-hei war-margin1">
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 warning-mar">
                        <p>Best Regards,</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-1  2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 warning-mar">
                        <p>Human Resource Manager</br>
                            HR Department
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the css I am using:

```
 .warning-mar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.warning-mar2 {
        margin-top: 8px !important;
    }
.warning-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right:15px;
}
.print-font {
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #e8e6e6;
}
.table-padd {
    padding:5px !important;
}
tr>td.print-black {
        background-color: #cecdcd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
.mima-logo {
    height: 76px;
}
.text-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.print-sett {
    line-height: 9px !important;    
    }
.bg_color {
        background-image:url('http://testing.sprucenetwork.com/assets/img/Apple-logo.png') !important;
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-position: unset !important;
        background-size:100% !important;
        z-index:1000000px !important;
    }   
    .bg_image {
        background-image:url('http://testing.sprucenetwork.com/assets/img/Apple-logo.png') !important;
        background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
        background-position: center !important;
        background-size:100% !important;
        z-index:10 !important;

    }
    .page-break2 {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;
    }   
@media print {

    .letter-head {
        padding-right:140px !important;
    }
    tr>td.print-black {
        background-color: #cecdcd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
    .text-bold {
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
    .warning-line-hei {
        line-height:17px !important;
        text-align:justify !important;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }

    .print-font2 {
        border:solid 0px #e8e6e600 !important;
        padding:10px 30px 0px 30px !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        font-family: calibri !important;
        text-align: justify !important;
    }
    .print-font {
        padding: 10px 50px 45px 50px !important;
        border:solid 0px #e8e6e600 !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        font-family: calibri !important;
        text-align: justify !important;
    }
    .warning-right {
        float: right !important;
        padding-right:30px !important;
    }
    .warning-mar {
        margin-top: 6px !important;
    }
    .war-margin1 {
        margin-top: 20px !important;
    }
    .warning-mar2 {
        margin-top: 8px !important;
    }
    .warning-top-mar {
        margin-top: 160px;
    }
    .bor-bot {
        border-bottom: solid 1px #000 !important;
    }
    .mima-logo {
        height: 66px !important;
    }
    .print-font-size {
        font-size:11px !important;
    }
    .print-head-size {
        font-size:20px !important;
    }
    .print-font-size2 {
        font-size:20px !important;
    }
    .print-sett {
        line-height: 9px !important;
        font-size: 11px !important;
    }
    .table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
        border:solid 1px #000 !important;
    } 
    .print-container {
        height:100% !important;
    }   
    .p-sett {
        visibility:hidden !important;
        color:#FFF !important:
    }
    .bg_image {
        background-image:url('http://testing.sprucenetwork.com/assets/img/Apple-logo.png') !important;
        background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
        background-position: unset !important;
        background-size:100% !important;
        z-index:10 !important;
    }
    .last-page {
        visibility:hidden !important:
    }
    .page-break {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;;
    }
    .page-break2 {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: bg_color class is for first print page it does not effect the issue that i have.

Answer (score 1):

From what i am seeing, you called the apple logo twice on your bg-color and bg image classes. As a result, two apple logos will appear. Removing either one will result in only 1 logo.

```
 .warning-mar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.warning-mar2 {
        margin-top: 8px !important;
    }
.warning-right {
    float: right;
    padding-right:15px;
}
.print-font {
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #e8e6e6;
}
.table-padd {
    padding:5px !important;
}
tr>td.print-black {
        background-color: #cecdcd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
.mima-logo {
    height: 76px;
}
.text-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.print-sett {
    line-height: 9px !important;    
    }
.bg_color {
        background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
        background-position: unset !important;
        background-size:100% !important;
        z-index:1000000px !important;
    }   
    .bg_image {
        background-image:url('http://testing.sprucenetwork.com/assets/img/Apple-logo.png') !important;
        background-position: center !important;

    }
    .page-break2 {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;
    }   
@media print {

    .letter-head {
        padding-right:140px !important;
    }
    tr>td.print-black {
        background-color: #cecdcd !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
    .text-bold {
        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
    .warning-line-hei {
        line-height:17px !important;
        text-align:justify !important;
    }
    p {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    }

    .print-font2 {
        border:solid 0px #e8e6e600 !important;
        padding:10px 30px 0px 30px !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        font-family: calibri !important;
        text-align: justify !important;
    }
    .print-font {
        padding: 10px 50px 45px 50px !important;
        border:solid 0px #e8e6e600 !important;
        font-size:14px !important;
        font-family: calibri !important;
        text-align: justify !important;
    }
    .warning-right {
        float: right !important;
        padding-right:30px !important;
    }
    .warning-mar {
        margin-top: 6px !important;
    }
    .war-margin1 {
        margin-top: 20px !important;
    }
    .warning-mar2 {
        margin-top: 8px !important;
    }
    .warning-top-mar {
        margin-top: 160px;
    }
    .bor-bot {
        border-bottom: solid 1px #000 !important;
    }
    .mima-logo {
        height: 66px !important;
    }
    .print-font-size {
        font-size:11px !important;
    }
    .print-head-size {
        font-size:20px !important;
    }
    .print-font-size2 {
        font-size:20px !important;
    }
    .print-sett {
        line-height: 9px !important;
        font-size: 11px !important;
    }
    .table-bordered > thead > tr > th, .table-bordered > tbody > tr > td {
        border:solid 1px #000 !important;
    } 
    .print-container {
        height:100% !important;
    }   
    .p-sett {
        visibility:hidden !important;
        color:#FFF !important:
    }
    .last-page {
        visibility:hidden !important:
    }
    .page-break {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;;
    }
    .page-break2 {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px!important;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm67vdph/

Comment: The reason the logo appears twice is background-repeat:repeat-y !important; in .bg_image.

Comment: what about the second issue in last image , if content finishes the image also stops and only half image is visible.

Comment: The reason why your logo is cut in half is because of your page-break property. Try adding a `page-break-inside: avoid;` to the container of your last paragraph and see if it works.

Comment: @Rizwan There is just no more content and since the background height is not bigger than the content height, the bg image is cut. Try to give the content div a min-height that fits the image.

Comment: my data is dynamic, and i don't know the actual height of my div content..